# Can't get whole data from Hbase using scanner with java API

Tags: filter, hbase

all:

I built a hbase cluster using CDH-5.4.10,everything work pretty well,unless some weird things happened when I get data out of hbase using scanner with java API.My scanner is set up like this.

```
 FilterList filterList=new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
 filterList.addFilter(new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,new BinaryPrefixComparator(Bytes.toBytes("I003-2017.02.22"))));//scan all data whose rowkey starts with 'I003-2017.02.22'
 Scan scanner = new Scan();
 scanner.setFilter(this.filterList);
```

The data that this scanner gets depends on the running environment,not sure if depends on the JRE, like getting whole data in my computer but only getting a few batch of data in my colleague's computer.we all use the same JDK-1.7.0_67.

My maven configuration:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
<artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sematext.hbasewd</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbasewd</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have googled this,but seems nobody ever met this situations.So I think there must be some wrong in my code or configuration, but I can't figure out the problem.

Any help will be appreciated!

---

Updated on 2017-02-23

My colleague try different JDK versions,and find out that it's related to the versions of JDK. It works well with JDK-some_version_x64,but fails with JDK-some_version_x86.

So I think it has relation with JDK version (x64,x86). Anyone know the root cause of this weird problem?

Comment: Use proper compatible versions and then try : https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_new_in_cdh_54.html.For example you are using hadoop-hdfs 2.2.0 in pom file whereas CDH 5.4.x implements HDFS 2.6.0.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I try different versions of hdfs,but the problem is still there.